# selenium + phantomjs can't render the page via js

Tags: selenium, scrapy, phantomjs

I'm using scrapy + selenium + phantomjs to get the data from web which has javascript loading the data. When i use chrome. it works well, but when i change the browser to phantomjs, it can't work(can't get the data loaded by javascript). Here is the code(windows 7 platform):

```
class MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self):
        #self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

    def process_request(self, request, spider):

        if r"http://wenshu.court.gov.cn/list/list/?sorttype=1&conditions=searchWord+QWJS+++%E5%85%A8%E6%96%87%E6%A3%80%E7%B4%A2:%E6%88%90%E9%83%BD%E9%93%B6%E8%A1%8C%E8%82%A1%E4%BB%BD%E6%9C%89%E9%99%90%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8" == request.url:

            self.driver.get(request.url)

            try:
                element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "dataItem")))
                body = self.driver.page_source
                return HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
            except:
                body = self.driver.page_source
                return HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
        else:
            pass

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: What happens actually? `WebDriverWait` waits for some element to appear, does it time out?

Comment: yes, it's time out, and i got the response of original html code with no data which should been loaded by javascrpit